# Error in Pro.ASP.NET.MVC.3.Framework from Adam Freeman book

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am following this book Pro.ASP.NET.MVC.3.Framework from Adam Freeman.
So I download the code and is generating this html code in his menu categories.

The html:

```
<a class="" href="/Chess%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20">Chess                                             </a>
```

The result when I press the link (obvious):

```
http://localhost:43190/Chess%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

I don't know somebody has this issue with this book.

I try in my global.asax:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

In my layout:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content( "~/Content/themes/base/images/favicon.ico" )" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And in my ninject controller:

```
  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {

            if (controllerType != null)
            {
                return (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }

        }
```

I don't know if someone have the same issue as me. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:
the real answer
ok I Understood know my sql was nvarchar so it generated blank space, i change to varchar and know not generate the blanck spaces

I read somewhere that adding .trim() it will do it and yes it work i dont understand why it put this (%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)

change this "category = link," for this
 "category = link.Trim(),"

the Menu.chtml

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product")
    @foreach (var link in Model)
    {
        @Html.RouteLink(link, new {
    controller = "Product",
    action = "List",
    category = link.Trim(),
    page = 1
    }, new {@class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected": null}
    )
    }
```

Comment: ok I Understood know my sql was nvarchar so it generated blank space, i change to varchar and know not generate the blanck spaces

Answer (score 1):

You should see to your MSSQL database. In the book the author uses `nchar` type for the column `Category`, you should use the type `nvarchar` instead. The `nchar` fills the end of the line with spaces (%20). Or you can set `ANSI-PADDING {off}` on the field in SQL Designer.